# MVC - HTML Table only displays outer border

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, html-table, border

I have an MVC view with a table that gets filled (from a partial view) with one set of `<thead><th></th></thead>` and then a collection of `<tr></tr>`. In the full view, I have my table markup as follows:

```
<table id="resultTable" border="1">
```

For some reason, the dynamically populated `<tr>`s and `<td>`s are not displaying a border.

I've done some searching but can't find the reason why.

Has anybody dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css:

```
#resultTable td {border: 1px solid #555;}
```

btw... your table rows added should be inside tbody tag.